# Will I be removed from groups on WhatsApp if I upgrade to a new phone?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, device-migration

I was removed from all groups before when I changed my number. Will the same happen if I change my phone? This time, I have the same number but a different phone.

Answer (score 5):

You retain your groups if you have the same number.

Off-topic, you may also want to check the [official documentation](https://faq.whatsapp.com/618575946635920) on how to back-up and restore your chat history to the new phone.

Comment: I've just replaced my phone, with the same number, and I can no longer send messages to any groups I was in as it says I'm no longer a participant. I can still see all the historical messages however. There was about a month between my last phone dying and its replacement coming online.

Answer (score 1):

Just backup your chat from
WhatsApp-> Settings-> Chat settings-> Backup conversations. This will back up your chats to a database on the WhatsApp folder of your SD card.

Copy the folder to your new phone and just install WhatsApp and activate your account from your number. Restore old chats when asked.

Answer (score 0):

No, you won't be removed from the group unless you don't change to a new phone number. Your groups will remain the same with the same phone number as earlier. If the group admin deletes the group or removed you, it depends.

In case you want to restore the message from the old phone to the new phone, back up all data from the Whatsapp backups directory which contains all your message backups as a `.crypt` file encrypted, and copy this file to your new phone and restore all your message.

Comment: Why does a data backup needed ? can u explain..?Removing group is controlled by the group admin. So how does backing up data help?

Comment: Once,  I reset back to factory without backup on my phone. Then after that when I installed whatsapp again, My previous data completely  removed. Hence thereafter,  I backup data, before proceeding any  installation of OTA update,reset etc, which can be restored easily.

Answer (score -1):

You won't be removed from groups if your number is same,

Comment: He will be in the group still even if he updates his number..